# Which forex brokerage should I choose if I want to fund my account with over a million dollars?

Tags: foreign-exchange, broker

I'm quite experienced with stock markets (mostly NYSE and NASDAQ in fact), over 85% of my wealth comes from it. In 2012 I would like to try the foreign exchange market, can you suggest any reliable forex broker?

Comment: have you considered sticking to currency ETFs and ETF options? its a very similar amount of leverage this way, just without the 24/5.5 trading capabilities

Comment: That's a good idea. I will look after what my current brokerage can offer.

Comment: Remember that a million isn't what it used to be. I'm assuming I'm going to want $1.8M, *not* including the house, before I even consider retiring.

Answer (score 3):

Oanda.com is a very respectable broker. They don't offer ridiculous leverage options of 200 to 1 that prove the downfall of people starting out in Forex. When I used them a few years back, they had good customer service and some nice charting tools.

Answer (score 1):

With your experience, I think you'd agree that trading over a standardized, regulated exchange is much more practical with the amount of capital you plan to trade with. That said, I'd highly advise you to consider FX futures at CME, cause spot forex at the bucket shops will give you a ton of avoidable operational risks.